# Compiling .h with .cpp using g++ on the same directory, error

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

I am learning C++ and I have a Class declaration in a `.h` file, and the definitions on a `.cpp` file. The `.h` file is as follows:

```
// matrix.h

class Matrix {
 private:
  int r; // number of rows
  int c; // number of columns
  double* d;
 public:
  Matrix(int nrows, int ncols, double ini = 0.0); // declaration of the constructor
  ~Matrix(); // declaration of the destructor
  inline double operator()(int i, int j) const;
  inline double& operator()(int i, int j);
};
```

And the `.cpp` is:

```
// matrix.cpp

#include "matrix.h"

Matrix::Matrix(int nrows, int ncols, double ini) {
  r = nrows;
  c = ncols;
  d = new double[nrows*ncols];
  for (int i = 0; i < nrows*ncols; i++) d[i] = ini;
}

Matrix::~Matrix() {
  delete[] d;
}

inline double Matrix::operator()(int i, int j) const {
  return d[i*c+j];
}

inline double& Matrix::operator()(int i, int j) {
  return d[i*c+j];
}
```

And the test file is:

```
// test.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "matrix.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  Matrix neo(2,2,1.0);
  cout << (neo(0,0) = 2.34) << endl;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Problem:** when I compile the `test.cpp` file using `g++ test.cpp`, or using `g++ test.cpp matrix.cpp`, I get the errors: `warning: inline function 'Matrix::operator()' is not defined` and `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`.

**Question:** What is failing? How can I understand what is happening?  Thanks for helping!

Comment: Get rid of the "inline" keyword everywhere you put it. Whatever you think it means, it doesn't mean that.

Comment: Either that or move the function implementations into the header, like `inline double& operator()(int i, int j) {return d[i*c+j];}`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I am following a book, that's why I have it there. The book explains that: "(...) the body of the operator deﬁnition is inserted into the code as it is being compiled. This makes the resulting program larger, but saves the execution time required for a function call." Do you think that's causing the problem? How can I understand what's going on better? Thanks for helping!

Comment: @GuilhermeSalomé The book is correct, but for that work, the caller has to be able to directly see the function implementation.  So in your case, it needs to be in the header.

Comment: Unrelated: A future bug will likely involve the Rule of Three. Forewarned is forearmed, so give this a read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The body of an `inline` function should be visible at all callsites of the function.

In your setup you need to move those two inline definitions from `matrix.cpp` to `matrix.h` ; or make them non-inline.